# How to propagate changes done outside my View in a WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a property called `IsVisible`:

```
public new bool IsVisible
{
    get { return base.IsVisible; }
    set
    {
        base.IsVisible = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "IsVisible" );
    }
}
```

So this property is set to `true` when left mouse button is down for the selected item in the`TreeView`. It works fine, but I also have a `CheckBox` I am trying to bind to the same property, two way. So whenever I change this property via left mouse button down, the `CheckBox` shows the IsVisible state if it's true. So this works partially.

But the problem is, each time when I set this property to true for an instance, all other layers' `IsVisible` property is set to false, but the `CheckBox`es don't show the changes. They still look checked.

So whenever I say:

```
layer.IsVisible = true;
```

all the other layers are set to false by the base class which I don't have access to the source code (shown above).

How can I make my app recognize this change?

Answer (score 2):

So you are hiding the IsVisible property of the base class, which doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  All checkboxes are binding to your class (not the base)?

Can you mimic the behavior of the base class by iterating through the necessary layers and making the same changes to your own properties (which obviously DO notify)?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am hiding it with the `new` keyword, so it works, it definitely binds to my class. As for mimicing the behavior, I could go through all the objects binded to my application, which would be the only way, otherwise there is no way to find out, which layers are hidden by the base class, because it's always a `clear all` action followed by the set `layer` to visible.

Comment: If you can drill down through the whole collection of your classes, you could simply create a method called "UpdateFromBase()" (or something like that) and in it just call this.IsVisible = base.IsVisible.